# Why I cannot find element in a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a DataTemplate in my XAML design.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dt1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="388">
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="titleText" Text="{Binding Path=titleText}" Foreground="White" FontSize="40" TextLineBounds="TrimToCapHeight" Margin="0,6,0,0" />
        </RelativePanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And I call it like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="r3" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dt1}"/>
```

And then I use the below code to try to find `titleText` inside of the `DataTemplate`.

```
public object FindChildInDT<T>(T inputElement, string childName)
{
    DataTemplate dt = (inputElement as ContentControl).ContentTemplate;
    DependencyObject dio = dt.LoadContent();
    foreach (var tb1 in FindVisualChildren<ContentControl>(dio))
    {
        if (tb1.Name == childName)
        {
            return tb1;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tts = FindChildInDT(r3, "titleText") as TextBlock;
    if (tts == null)
        Debug.WriteLine("tts is null");
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("tts is not null");
}
```

But I failed, the log is below:

```
tts is null
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Observing your code, I guess you want to change the content of the TextBlock, then I suggest you change it using data binding. If you encounter the bound data and can't display on the UI after the modification, then I will also give an example in answer. Looking forward to your reply. :)

Comment: The real reason is a little bit complex. I explain is in another post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109481/set-the-size-of-frame-image   Please check, thanks! @Richasy

Comment: I see. The layout may have some problems. I will keep track of this issue, but it seems that I need to help you solve the other problem first.

Comment: @Richasy Thank you! The other problem is the root problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @TomXue: When do you set the `Content` of  `r3` and which element are handling the `Loaded` event for?

Comment: @TomXue Hi, I noticed that you have marked my answer in another question. Does it solve the problem you are faced with? If so, do you need to know something about how to do data binding on this question?