# Set the size of frame image

Tags: uwp

**Question 1:**

I have a `DataTemplate` as below. And in my layout I need to put Image `tipFrame` below `TextBlock` `tipText`. `tipText's` text will change according to pulled server text, hence `tipFrame's` width should change accordingly to cover tipText.

But the issue is that `tipText's` parent control, the `RelativePanel's` width is big, e.g. 1800. And due to `tipText's` Margin setting `Margin="35,7,100,0"`, so tipText's width is `1800 - 35 = 1765`, which does not match its content size. E.g. the content maybe only `"hi"`. That causes the frame's size cannot be set properly.
How to solve it?

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="singleRow">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="388">
                <RelativePanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="titleText" Text="{Binding Path=titleText}" Foreground="White" FontSize="40" TextLineBounds="TrimToCapHeight" Margin="0,6,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tipText" Text="try something" FontSize="20" Foreground="#B9B9B9" RelativePanel.RightOf="titleText"
                               Margin="35,7,0,0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                    <Image x:Name="tipFrame" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Template/list1/tipFrame.png" RelativePanel.RightOf="titleText" 
                           Height="36" Width="{Binding ElementName=tipTextShadow,Path=Width}" Stretch="Fill"
                           Margin="35,5,0,0"/>
```

The tipFrame image is attached below:

[image]

**Question 2:**

I set the Stretch mode of the above image as `Stretch="Fill"`. If the the image's width is set too big, then the 4 corners' radius of it is changed too much, and is rather ugly. How to solve it?

**More:**

I add a new picture to illustrate my issue:

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom. Let me talk about my guess. Do you want the text to be on the left and the image on the right, and the two TextBlocks are aligned up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some of my advice:

1. If your content width and height are variable, then I don't recommend using `RelativePanel` for layout, but `Grid` is recommended.
2. The image you give is a rounded rectangle. Excessive stretching will inevitably distort the image. Try `Stretch="Uniform"` or `Stretch="UniformToFill"`

This is the layout suggestion I gave:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="singleRow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="titleText" Foreground="White" FontSize="40" TextLineBounds="TrimToCapHeight" Margin="0,6,0,0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="tipText" Text="try something" FontSize="20" Foreground="#B9B9B9"
                       Margin="35,7,0,0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="tipFrame" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Template/list1/tipFrame.png" Grid.Column="1"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill"
               Height="30"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**tips**

The `*` in the Grid Row/Column Definitions indicates the remaining area, which prevents you from manually setting the width/height.

Best regards.